# Question about two sets bounded from above.

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

Let A and B be two nonempty sets that are bounded from above.

1) lets suppose that that there is $\epsilon>0$ such that for each $a\in A$ there is b such that $a + \epsilon < b$. prove that $supA<supB$

2) lets suppose now that for every $a\in A$ there is $\epsilon<0$ and $b\in B$ such that  $a + \epsilon < b$. prove or disprove that  $supA<supB$

Comment: May you check whether the conclusion for question 1 is correct? And for question 2, should $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: for first one I think what u wrote is a reasonable proof. second one doesn't work because it says in question that $\epsilon>0$

Comment: Why it doesn't work? For $a\in(0,1)$, you can find $b\in(a,1)$, then just set $\epsilon=(b-a)/2>0$.

Comment: what if i choose a=1? then what $\epsilon$ can I add to it so it can smaller than $b \in_B$ ? if B={0,1} too?

Comment: Note in my definition, $1$ doesn't belong to $A$, so you can't choose $1$. The condition is $\forall a\in A$...$

Comment: then what  " Let $A=B=(0,1)$  " means ?

Comment: sorry the inequality sign must be the opposite, in both questions. $supA<supB$ .

Comment: It means set $A,B$ be open interval from 0 to 1.

Comment: so now question one is still right. what about 2, do u think is still right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18318/discussion-between-firas-ali-abdel-ghani-and-john-zhang).

Comment: Yes. Because my example $sup A=sup B$, which is still a valid counterexample.

Comment: I got everything now. thanks. I forgot about the (), i thought its just a normal set that includes two numbers.

Comment: I am glad it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $\sup A-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound of A, $\exists a\in A$ s.t. $a>\sup A-\epsilon$, by assumption, $\exists b$ such that $a + \epsilon < b$, hence $b>a + \epsilon>\sup A$. Hence $\sup B>\sup A$.

The second is wrong. Let $A=B=(0,1)$ satisfies the condition, $\sup A=\sup B=1$